# VB.NET Draw focus rectangle

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I need to a draw common dotted focus rectangle.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent to

```
Public Declare Function DrawFocusRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
```

in the GDI+ classes / System.Drawing of VB.NET that is managed and that will accomplish the same.

Thank you!

I need to edit my post: For some reason, ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle does not persist on a bitmap.

I would therefore like to ask if there is a different method that persists on a bitmap as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ControlPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has many useful tools for painting common control-related graphical elements.  It includes a [`DrawFocusRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2czzc46%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which should do what you are looking for.  From the MSDN:

> Draws a focus rectangle on the specified graphics surface and within the specified bounds.
>  ... 
>  A focus rectangle is a dotted rectangle that Windows uses to indicate what control has the current keyboard focus.

It's a `Shared` method, so you can call it without creating an instance of the `ControlPaint` class, for instance:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(Button1.CreateGraphics(), Button1.ClientRectangle)
End Sub
```

There is also an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs6sf590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the method which allows you to specify the foreground and background color.

It's in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, defined by the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` library, so it's not technically part of the `System.Drawing` library, like you requested, but you should be able to reference and use that library even outside of a WinForm application, if necessary.